# Iterate json data in select option

Tags: getjson

I am using $.getJSON and it is return below json data.

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 2,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
    "aaData": [
        {
            "student": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "gaurav"
            }
        },
        {
            "student": {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "abhishek"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to put student id and name into the select option value.
Html will be like this :

```
<select name='stud'>
<option id='1'>gaurav</option>
<option id='1'>abhishek</option>
</select>
```

When am use JSON.stringify it is returning object object.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after ? (assumes that you are using jQuery on your page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var json = {
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 2,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
    "aaData": [
        {
            "student": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "gaurav"
            }
        }, {
            "student": {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "abhishek"
            }
        }
    ]
};

json.aaData.forEach(function(value) {   
    var student = value.student
     $('#mySelect')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",student.id)
         .text(student.name)); 
});
</script>

<select id='mySelect' name='stud'>
</select>
```

See working example on here: http://jsfiddle.net/r5nn5wqu/

Comment: Thank u very much. Its help me a lot.
 http://jsfiddle.net/r5nn5wqu/ this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    $('select[name="stud"]').append('<option id="'+key+'" value="'+value+'"');
  });
}
```